# Datastore: Is there plan to add GQLQuery support?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I am using [gcloud-python](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/) library for a project which needs to serve following use case:

- Get a batch of entities with a subset of its properties (projection)
- `gcloud.datastore.api.get_multi()` provides me batch get but not projection
- and `gcloud.datastore.api.Query()` provides me projection but not batch get (like a `IN` query)

AFAIK, GQLQuery provides both IN query(batch get) and projections. Is there a plan to support GQLQueries in gcloud-python library? OR, is there another way to get batching and projection in single request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to request a subset of an entities properties. When you have the list of keys that you need, you should use `get_multi()`.

### Projection Query Background

In Datastore, projection queries are simply index scans.

For example, consider you are writing the query `SELECT * FROM MyKind ORDER BY myFirstProp, mySecondProp`. This query will execute against an index: `Index(MyKind, myFirstProp, mySecondProp)`. This index may look something like:

```
myFirstProp | mySecondProp | __key__
------------------------------------
a             1              k1
a             2              k2
b             1              k3
```

For each result in the index, Datastore then looks up the key associated with that index result. If you do a projection query where you project only `myFirstProp` or `mySecondProp` or both, Datastore can avoid doing the random access lookup to find the associated entity for each result. This is generally where you get the large performance gain from using projections -- not from the savings of transporting it over the network.

Likewise, if you know the list of keys that you need, you can lookup the key directly -- there is no need to look in an index first.

### IN Operator

In Python GQL ([not in the similar Cloud Datastore GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference#unsupported_features_and_behavior_differences_from_mysqlpython_gql)), there is the `IN` operator, which allows you to write a query that looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE myFirstProp IN ['a', 'b'].
```

However, Datastore does not actually support this query natively. Inside the python client, this will get converted into [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form):

```
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE myFirstProp = 'a'
UNION
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE myFirstProp = 'b'
```

This means for each value inside your `IN`, you'll be issuing a separate Datastore query.